# word frequency graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a graph with the following codes that I took from 
https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html#word-frequencies

The following worked for me with my variables

```
library(tidyr)

frequency <- bind_rows(mutate(tidy_bronte, author = "abc"),
                       mutate(tidy_hgwells, author = "def") %>% 
  mutate(word = str_extract(word, "[a-z']+")) %>%
  count(author, word) %>%
  group_by(author) %>%
  mutate(proportion = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  spread(author, proportion) %>% 
  gather(author, proportion, `abc`)
```

However when I wrote the following for the graph it did not work

```
library(scales)
ggplot(frequency, aes(x = proportion, y = `abc`, color = abs(`abc` - proportion))) +
  geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.001), low = "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") +
  facet_wrap(~author, ncol = 2) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(y = "abc", x = NULL)
```

I get the following error

> `Error: object 'abc' not found

If it does not find `abc`, how did the first code work?

Comment: Did you load `ggplot2`. Also where is this data from? Is it part of `tidytext` or some other package? Please add a `dput` of the data you're using.

Comment: when I write `y = "abc"` It gives me `Error in "abc" - proportion : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. This back tick is the same in the code as I put the html link. And yes it is `tidytext` .

Comment: @NelsonGon, it is not a mistake, but the back ticks are needed because the column names have spaces in them. The OP has a missing bracket because he removed one of the books.

Comment: I realised and answered below. Thanks! @phiver

Comment: That worked very well. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you omitted one of the books(`tidy_books`). You omitted this code: `mutate(tidy_books, author = "Jane Austen")`
 I've not included it as it would require me rereading the book. Try to find the chapter that has that and replace it as I've commented in the code:

```
#replace ghi with Jane as in the book
freq<-bind_rows(mutate(tidy_bronte, author = "abc"),
          mutate(tidy_hgwells, author = "def"),
          mutate(tidy_bronte,author="ghi")) %>% 
            mutate(word = str_extract(word, "[a-z']+")) %>%
            count(author, word) %>%
            group_by(author) %>%
            mutate(proportion = n / sum(n)) %>% 
            select(-n) %>% 
            spread(author, proportion) %>% 
            gather("author", "proportion",2:3)

 ggplot(freq, aes(x = proportion, y =`ghi`, color = abs(`ghi` - proportion))) +
            geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
            geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
            geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) +
            scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format())+ 
            scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
            scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.001), low = "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") +
            facet_wrap(~author, ncol = 2) +
            theme(legend.position="none") +
            labs(y = "abc", x = NULL)
```

Here is my output for representative purposes:
[image]